# Pandas: Lookup value in other dataframe and document state

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes... First dataframe (df1) as a list of server with further informationen... The second dataframe (df2) is almost the same but, doesn't include systems which are dismantle.

I want to add a column to df1, if the server was not found in df2.

df1:
[dataframe df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pgKj.png)

df2:
[dataframe2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pao7M.png)

Comment: include the sample source files (e.g. csv files) for both dataframes. and also show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a left merge on `df1` and `df2` using [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and turn on `indicator=` parameter:

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on='Server', how='left', indicator='MissingServer')
```

Then, on the resulting dataframe, you can look at the column `MissingServer` and check for those marked as `left_only`.  Those will be the servers found in `df1` but not in `df2`.

Comment: Hey SeaBean, thank you for your help and response! It works expected, even with more than 20000 rows :)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for your problem.

```py
active = pd.DataFrame({
    'server':['a','b'],
    'group': [1,2]
})
total = pd.DataFrame({
    'server':['a','b','c'],
    'group': [1,2,3]
})
active['Status']= True
```

| server | group | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | True |
| b | 2 | True |

| server | group |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

```py
total= total.merge(active,how='left')
total.fillna(False,inplace=True)
total
```

| server | group | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | True |
| b | 2 | True |
| c | 3 | False |

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks! Your soultion works as well. Good idea!

Comment: Happy to hear that!